# Dynamic redirection in Google Sites with HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

I wish to make a redirection in a Google Apps Script embedded in a Google Site. I use HtmlService: when the user click a button, it starts a function containing `window.location = adress_I_want_to_redirect`.

Unfortunatly, it doesn't work. I tried with jQuery and `$('location').href(adress_I_want_to_redirect)` but it doesn't work either (quite logical ^^). Console displays `The property 'href' is not writable.`

Do you know an other way to do redirection which will work in GAS?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the Caja engine is preventing you from doing a redirection like this. You may need to use a regular anchor tag instead.

Comment: +Eric Koleda this anchor only seems to work if you add the `target ='_blank'`to the anchor tag. If not I seem to bump into the X-Frame-Options error that does not permit framing, is that correct?